# dig sometimes return SOA sometimes A record

Tags: dns, dig

I have a DNS record registered that occasionally will return the A record, but most of the time returns the SOA when I use `dig`.

This record has existed for several weeks and yet it seems to not have propagated.

It's registered with Google Cloud DNS.

Do I just need to keep `digging` until the record is propagated correctly?